# How to remove searchView Icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview, imageicon

I have simple SearchView `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` not `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

I want to remove SearchView icon when its on focus `QueryTextFocusChangeListener`.

After I google it, I found two solutions which is for `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

1. This one I cannot find `R.id.search_mag_icon`, so it didn't work.

   `SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchViewItem.getActionView();         searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon).setVisibility(View.GONE);`
2. Setting `app:searchIcon="@null"` makes icon gone, but its gone at the beginning. I want to remove icon only when its on focus. I tried set `searchIcon="@null"`  programmatically but I cannot find it.

   `app:searchIcon="@null"`

Again, I'm using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`. Please help me. I spent long time but still

suffering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done programmatically. Check out `mSearchHintIcon` in `SearchView.java` (android source). It is private.

Try 'app:searchHintIcon':

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
      android:id="@+id/main_sv"
      app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/blank_placeholder_drawable"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Or you can also change `android:tint="#fafafa"` to any placeholder drawable to match the background color.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using AppCompat use

```
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:searchIcon="@null"
```

Else use android in place of app in above code as

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:searchIcon="@null"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this with your `SearchView`:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```